On the diameter of intersection of nested closed bounded convex (not necessarily compact) sets in Banach spaces
Let $\{H_n\}$ be a sequence of non-empty closed, bounded and convex sets in a Banach space $X$ with $H_{n+1}\subseteq H_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Denote $\delta(A)= \sup\{\|x-y\|: x, y\in A\},$ the diameter of the set $A,$ where $A$ is a bounded subset of $X.$ If $\delta(H_n)\to r$ for some positive real $r,$ then what can be said about $\delta(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n)?$ At least can we say that $\delta(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n)$ is a positive number? What happens if $X$ is strictly convex?
My Approach: As $\{\delta(H_n)\}$ is a bounded below and non-increasing sequence in $\mathbb{R},$ it converges to the Infinium. Therefore, $r=\inf \{\delta(H_n): n\geq 1\}.$ Clearly, $\delta(H_n)\geq r$ for all $n\geq 1.$ After this, how we can proceed?

What about
$$
H_n
:=
\{
x \in \ell^2
\mid
\|x\|_{\ell^2} \le 1 \text{ and }
x_i = 0 \text{ for } i = 1,\ldots,n
\}
$$
?

Thank you so much @gerw
